# How to update kernel version without upgrading kernel?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, updates, versions

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with linux kernel 4.13. However I had to manually install linux kernel 4.4 to support local legacy software and hardware.

I'm currently running

```
$uname -r
4.4.0-128-generic
```

How do I update this kernel to [v4.4.138](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.138/) without upgrading the kernel I initially installed?

I.e. how can upgrade my kernel from 4.4.128 to 4.4.138 without upgrading to my initially installed kernel, 4.13?

Edit:
I know that I could do this update/upgrade manually, but I'm hoping that there is a more clever solution via manipulation of using sudo apt-get dist-upgrade or the like....

Comment: Install 4.4.138 exactly the same way as 4.4.128?

Comment: @AlexP- I definitely could do that, but I'm hoping there is a slicker solution that I haven't been able to find or create. I've tried playing around with arguments to apt-get dist-upgrade, but nothing has worked so far....

Comment: How you "manually installed" 4.4.0-128 is not clear. To me, "manually installed" means you compiled from source, and installed using a makefile. To others, "manually installed" means you manually downloaded a deb from some non-Ubuntu place, and told dpkg to install that deb. Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

16.04 was originally released with kernel 4.4. What you've installed must have been 16.04.4, which has [UES](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), or in other words, the kernel and graphical components from 17.10, while all the rest is the same.

What you may want to do is to install the [original 16.04](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.1/). This way, you'll only have kernel 4.4, and won't have to bother with "updating without upgrading".